# Can I bind multiple attacks from a class to hotkeys?

Tags: diablo-iii

In some of the earlier beta screenshots, a Monk was shown with two spirit generators (blue spells) bound to Mouse 1 and 2.  Is this functionality totally gone or can you mix up your abilities and keybinds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable "Elective Mode" in the options.  This will allow you to assign any skill you have unlocked to any slot you have unlocked.

Here's a [more detailed explanation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2PADdI2KBc).